# How to set Records per page limit in OBOUT Grid?

Tags: c#, asp.net, obout

I want to set Records per page limit should be always all in a grid in ASP.Net.

By default the limit is in 20 records per page, But It should be "All" records per page.

I am still new in ASP.NET. May I know how to do it in ASP.NET. ?

Comment: well if there is all in option in paging dropdown than there is no way to show the pager when all is selected... correct me if wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add the ALL option to the page size selector, you need to append -1 to the value of the PageSizeOptions property.

```
<obout:Grid ID="grid1" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" AllowPageSizeSelection="true" PageSizeOptions="1,2,3,4,5,6,-1"></obout:Grid>
```

You can follow this link for more detail:
http://www.obout.com/grid/aspnet_paging_all_records.aspx 
http://www.obout.com/grid/grid_paging_customize.aspx

Comment: The answer is in that link. Thank you  @ Rojalin Sahoo